# graph traversal with counts in network for each node

Tags: orientdb

This is probably a basic question, but going thru the sparse docs I cannot figure out how to do this.  I am new to orientdb and graphs in general.

I have simple graph.

users - vertices
hasInAddressBook - edge
introduced

user->hasInAddressBoom->user
user->introducedToNetwork->user

what I am trying to find is the following:

given a user name -> how many users in their addressbook along with names
given a user name -> who did they introduce without regards to depth

example data:
    john -> hasInAddressBook ->Doe
    john -> hasinAddressbook -> susan
    john -> hasInAddressBook > lucy
    john -> hasInAddressBook -> Smith
    john -> hasInAddressBook -> john1

```
john -> introducedToNetowrk -> Doe

Doe -> hasinAddressbook -> susan
Doe -> hasInAddressBook > lucy
Doe -> hasInAddressBook -> New1
Doe -> hasInAddressBook -> John

Doe -> introducedToNetwork -> susan
Doe -> introducedToNetwork -> Smith
Doe -> introducedToNetwork -> New1
```

Now what I need is as follows:

Total people in Johns Network: result should be 4 , since john introduced Doe and Doe introduced 3 people 1+3 = 4

Total people in Doe network: = 3

Total in John's addressbook: 5

Total in Doe's addressbook: 4

There is no limit to depth.

what would be SQL/node.js code that I would use to get above results ( along with the counts, I will also need the indiv. for each vertex..

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the screen when I execute the query from Studio

[image]

Comment: Alessandro, Thanks for the help.  it works in studio :-) . I was typing the commands in the console before.  While doing from node.js how would I bundle these since I won't be running from studio..Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,out("hasInAddressBoom").size() as hasInAddressBoom,sum($p.size(),-1) as introducedToNetwork FROM User
LET $p = ( SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE out("introducedToNetwork") FROM $parent.$current))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..however the second statement fails..can you elaborate on what the above queries are doing ? i am sorry but I am very new to orientdb...the first query runs and gives me 5 rows..but second one fails and gives the fillowing [code] !Unrecognized command: 'LET $p = ( SELECT FROM (TRAVERSE out("introducedToNetwork") FROM $parent.$current))'

Comment: You must select and execute all the two lines together

Comment: I tried looking at the docs...how do you do that..I cut and pasted ..do you need enclose in a begin block? but that seems to be for transactions.. using \ between statements doesnt work..thanks for your time...the docs could use some work :-)